# Spark 1.5.2: NaN while calculating stddev

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting NaN while calculating standard deviation (stddev). This is a very simple use case as described below:

```scala
 val df = Seq(("1",19603176695L),("2", 26438904194L),("3",29640527990L),("4",21034972928L),("5", 23975L)).toDF("v","data")
```

I have the stddev defined as an UDF:

```scala
def stddev(col: Column) = {
        sqrt(mean(col*col) - mean(col)*mean(col))
 }
```

I'm getting `NaN` when I call the UDF as shown below:

```scala
df.agg(stddev(col("data")).as("stddev")).show()
```

It produces the following:

```
+------+
|stddev|
+------+
|   NaN|
+------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your data, both `mean(col*col)` and `mean(col)*mean(col)` will be larger than a maximum value of `Long`. You can try casting input columns to `double` first:

```
df.agg(stddev(col("data").cast("double")).as("stddev"))
```

but in general it won't be particularly stable on very large numbers.

Comment: How does Spark 1.6 handle large numbers? Is there a better way to calculate stddev in this case?

Comment: Because `Double.MaxValue` is roughly 1.79e308 while `Long.MaxValue` is around 9.2e18.

Comment: Yes, built-in functions in 1.6 have better numerical properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "but in general it won't be particularly stable on very large numbers..."?